# What role does this ground crew member fulfill?

Tags: military, ground-operations, airshow

At the Miramar airshow a couple of weeks ago I noticed that in addition to the crew chief of each Blue Angel there was one additional individual standing behind the crew chiefs between aircraft #3 and #4:

[image]

What role does that individual fulfill?

Comment: Head crew chief?

Comment: Looking through the [Blue Angels team roster](https://www.blueangels.navy.mil/team/enlisted.asp) these are most likely the "Crew Coordinators".